# Laravel 4.2 get records of current month

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4.2

i got a problem in my project i am using `Laravel 4.2`.

Piece of code which have problem..

```
$xx = xx::where('user_id','=',$user_id)
            ->where('date','>=',$first_day) //$first_day is first day of any month
            ->where('date','<=',$last_day)//$last_day is last day of same month
            ->get();

print_r($xx);die(); 
//records present but empty array for current month but working fine for any previous month
```

Result

> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( ) )

Laravel last query log

> Array ( [query] => select * from `x_xx` where `user_id` = ? and `date`
>   = ? and `date` <= ? [bindings] => Array ( [0] => 17 [1] => 2016-04-1 [2] => 2016-04-30 ) [time] => 0.69 )

Running in mysql phpmyadmin i got 15 records

> select * from `x_xx` where `user_id` = 17 and `date` >= '2016-04-1'
>    and `date` <= '2016-04-30' //15 total records found in mysql

Comment: Your laravel last query log shows you are doing an `=` SELECT for one of the `date` columns instead of `>=`

Comment: @OliverQueen thanks for keen eyes but i found solution it was in `firstdate` variable see its showing `2016-04-1` i used `2016-04-01` and works fine :)